# How to find Substring as a number from a string in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Below code some time works fine but some time showing error. In MM case previously my output was 8 instead of 08. But now am getting 08 as a string with error Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17),
hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021).

```
echo off
CD /d C:\Windows\System32\wbem\

FOR /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%x

SET /a YYYY=%MyDate:~0,4%

SET /a MM=%MyDate:~4,2%

SET /a DD=%MyDate:~6,2%

echo %YYYY%
echo %MM%
echo %DD%
```

Comment: Now I got, when SET /a MM=%MyDate:~4,2% result is 08 that time only am getting this error.

Comment: But I want in number format if result is 05 i need only 5. If my result is 11 or 10 or 12 that time I need 11 or 10 or 12 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET /a MM=1%MyDate:~4,2%-100

SET /a DD=1%MyDate:~6,2%-100
```

is the standard method of overcoming this problem.

The reverse, to obtain a 2-character leading-zero-filled version, is

set /a MM+=100
   set "MM=%MM:~-2%"

Comment: +1 Neat method for handling this... _must remember for the future_ (I've used variants of Mofi's answer and explicitly checked for a leading zero in the past).

Answer (score 0):

Windows command interpreter uses the C/C++ function [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) with value `0` for third function parameter `base`. This means any number string starting with 0 is interpreted as octal number. `08` and `09` are not valid octal numbers as the octal system has only the digits 0 to 7.

The solution is not using an arithmetic expression and instead use just string substitutions:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "MyDate=%%I"
set "Year=%MyDate:~0,4%"
if "%MyDate:~4,1%" == "0" ( set "Month=%MyDate:~5,1%" ) else set "Month=%MyDate:~4,2%"
if "%MyDate:~6,1%" == "0" ( set "Day=%MyDate:~7,1%" ) else set "Day=%MyDate:~6,2%"
echo Year:  %Year%
echo Month: %Month%
echo Day:   %Day%
endlocal
```

This batch code outputs:

```
Year:  2017
Month: 8
Day:   24
```

The UTF-16 Little Endian encoded output of used **WMIC** command is:

```
 
 
LocalDateTime=20170824150309.315000+120
```

Only `20170824150309` is assigned to environment variable `MyDate` because of `tokens=2 delims==.` which is processed further by the next 3 command lines after **FOR** command line using just string substitutions and not arithmetic expressions which is no help here to remove a leading zero.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic os /?`
- `wmic os get /?`
- `wmic os get localdatetime /?`